# What is a "Variant" in Drupal?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I tried to read a bit about what is actually a **Variant** in Drupal (and especially in [Ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools)).

But the 2-3 explanations I read were not clear enough for me. It was a wired experience for me since I've already learnt some "similar" Drupal unique terms such as *Drupal argument*, *Contexual filter*, *Page* (Drupal), *Entity*, *Node*, etc.

So what is a **Variant** and why do we need them? Please use the simplest explanation you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"***Variants***" are typically used / related to "Page Manager", which is part of the [CTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) module. The "simplest explanation***" is ... not "simple" to provide. However there is an interesting (amazing?) video intro about it: refer to [Learn Page manager! Part 3: Variants and selection rules](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/variants-and-selection-rules).

While you're at it, you may want to look at the entire (impressive) video series around there, i.e. [Learn Page manager!](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-page-manager). Here is a summary of the entire set of videos about this topic:

> - Page manager allows you to collect and manage contextual information in a flexible and consistent way. It is an important part of building infrastructure on Drupal websites, and you should know how to use this module.
> - The screencast series is targeted at experienced Drupal developers.
> - Episodes 1, 2 and 3 introduces the most basic concepts, such as custom pages, variants, selection rules and (to some extent) contextual objects.
> - Episodes 4, 5, 6 and 7 talk about Panels, with emphasis on Views integration but also some words on efficient caching.
> - Episodes 8 and 9 about access control, menu items, and not least the little-known but very useful Contextual Administration module.
> - Episodes 10 and 11 talks more about using contextual objects in Page manager, including using Views as context. This is, imho, where the real power in Page manager is.
> - Episodes 12 and 13 collects various bits and pieces, such as how to use Panels to easily rearrange the node edit form, import/export settings, and some extra modules that can be used with Page manager.

Some more recommended (free) tutorials that you may want to consider, and which will help a lot to understand the typical Drupal terminology in your question:

- The 32 (!!!) great video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework), organized in 7 chapters, about the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.
- A similar [set of 8 video tutorials](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-flag) about the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module.
- The [set of 30 video tutorials](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/taming-the-beast-learn-views) about the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

In Drupal 8, [Page Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager) has become a separated module, while formerly (up to Drupal 7), it was part of the [CTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) module. Here are some more quotes from the (D8 related) project page:

> It supports the creation of new pages, and allows placing blocks within that page.
>
> Like Drupal 7's Page Manager, it provides a concept of "page variants", each with their own selection conditions.
>
> Additionally, it can be used to take over an existing page, like overriding /node/% to change what is displayed when viewing a node.
>
> It utilizes the core `Conditions`, `Context`, and `Blocks` APIs to accomplish this.

So that's part of the changes coming up in the [CTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) module in D8.

Comment: I've heard something like this: In Drupal8 Ctools is going to change very much, some of the terms would be replaced (or something of the sort)... Have your also heard of such thing?